# Want to push element in to array of state variable

Tags: reactjs

I want to push element in array of state variable on each click of check box.
The problem is when i click on checkbox the value get pushed into array but when i click another checkbox array washout old value and only one value is present in it.

```
export default class Demo extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            attachmentList : []
        };
    }
    addAttachmentid = (e) => {

        console.log("1st",this.state.attachmentList)
        if(e.target.checked){
            this.setState({

                 attachmentList:this.state.attachmentList.push(e.target.value)
            });
        }
        else{
            this.setState({
                attachmentList:this.state.attachmentList.pop(e.target.value)
            });
        }

        console.log("attachmentlist",this.state.attachmentList)
    }
        render(){
             return (
                   <input type="checkbox" value="20" onChange={this.addAttachmentid} />
                   <input type="checkbox" value="21" onChange={this.addAttachmentid} />
                   <input type="checkbox" value="22" onChange={this.addAttachmentid} />
             )
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because `pop` method returns the removed item doesn't return the whole array. You could use `filter` to do this.

```
const filteredList = this.state.attachmentList.filter(item => item !== e.target.value);

// set this in the state.
```

Pop Method Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop

Comment: no Yash it's not because of pop. if checkbox is checked after clicking it it will push otherwise it will pop

Answer (score 1):

We should never mutate state(array in your case)

Here is the working code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    attachmentList: [],
    checkBoxValue: ["20", "21", "22"]
  };
  addAttachmentid = ({ target: { value, checked } }) => {
    console.log("1st", this.state.attachmentList);
    let attachement = [...this.state.attachmentList];

    if (checked) {
      attachement.push(value);
    } else {
      attachement.pop(value);
    }
    console.log("2nd", attachement);
    this.setState({
      attachmentList: attachement
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.state.checkBoxValue.map(value => {
          return (
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value={value}
              onChange={this.addAttachmentid}
            />
          );
        })}
      </>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: By doing `let attachement = [...this.state.attachmentList];` you're relying on the current value of state for setting a new one. However, since `setState` works async, it might have been changed meanwhile by some other function calls. It's safer to use functional form of setState.

Comment: Yes you are correct, it's always safer in a complex application to use functional form, but for small functions in which state is used only in that function, I prefer to use object style instead of functional as it supports better readability of code for me. In the end it's about personal preference and complexity of state sharing.

Comment: still not solved issue , did you get what exactly output i need ? i need 20,21,22 in attachmentList after checking all three checkboxes

Comment: Try  [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-johnson-l7mtj) as you check/uncheck on checkbox you will see those values printed and popped.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mutate the state directly, use array spread and `filter` instead:

```
  addAttachmentid = e => {
    console.log("1st", this.state.attachmentList);
    const { checked, value } = e.target;

    this.setState(
      state => {
        if (checked) {
          return {
            attachmentList: [...state.attachmentList, value]
          };
        }
        return {
          attachmentList: state.attachmentList.filter(
            attachment => attachment !== value
          )
        };
      },
      () => {
        console.log("attachmentlist", this.state.attachmentList);
      }
    );
  };
```

A few other things:

- Use functional form of `setState` if your next state depends on the previous state
- If you want to check the new state right after setting it, use callback function to the `setState`.

I've recently wrote a [post](https://claritydev.net/blog/the-most-common-mistakes-when-using-react) about these and a few other common mistakes with React.

Answer (score 0):

Please filter out the elemnt when we un check

```
attachement = this.state.attachmentList.filter((item) =>  item !== e.target.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially just update the state, but spread it's previous state:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    attachmentList: [...prevState.attachmentList, e.target.value],
}));
```

Then, when you want to remove it you can do a similar thing:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    attachmentList: prevState.attachmentList.filter(value => value !== e.target.value),
}));
```